# How to rollback database change in production after few hours or days

Tags: oracle

We are using Oracle 12c in production. Lets say there was release that went to production on Sunday and then some hours or some days later(e.g. Tuesday) we realized that we need to rollback the changes we did, assume there were DDL schema changes, along with DML changes which could be inserts, updates, deletes.

What is the best practice to rollback the changes? we can not restore database from backup because backup was from Sunday and there is data from Sunday to lets say Tuesday.

Just want to know what is the best practice for rolling back database changes in Oracle 12c.

Comment: "Just want to know what is the best practice for rolling back database changes in Oracle 12c." -- Restoring from a backup should have a pretty high rank here. So you'd probably want to make sure that there are enough restore points in your backup. That seems to be your actual problem here.

Comment: How often should we create a restore point and how do we rollback the changes of DDL and DML

Comment: This question is more suitable for [dba.se], as it's not programming related.

Comment: @user2101374: That depends on how much of the data you can sacrifice in the worst case. The lesser, the more frequent you have to make backups.

Comment: Ideally sacrifice no data at all? Not doable?

Comment: This is hard to answer in general because a great deal will depend on the specifics of the change.  If your DDL changes, for example, remove a column from a parent table and create a 1:n child table with that attribute, rolling back the DDL change while keeping the three days of additional data would require copying the data from the new child table back to the parent table, handling the situation where there were multiple child rows, and then dropping the child table.  That would realistically need to be a rollback script that was specific to the change.

Comment: Depending on your Oracle version and edition and how much additional development complexity you want to deal with, one possibility would be to use a separate edition for the changes and let the two editions exist side by side for a few days before you fully migrate to the new edition.  But that would mean that, for example, every change would need to deploy with code that knows how to synchronize data between the editions which is going to be additional development work.  And you're still in trouble if you discover problems after the new edition is made live.

Comment: @user2101374 - If you are not using editioning, then unless you have a custom uninstall script to undo your DDL and none of your data changes depend on that DDL (like an insert that depends on a change to a column size), there is no way to restore from backup, flashback, etc. without losing your data changes. If you must keep the data then you must fix the schema through another release (moving forward), not roll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making a rollout to Production, the best technique to go back is FLASHBACK DATABASE.

You can read more here

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9012.htm#SQLRF01801

The idea is to create a restore point flashback guarantee that you can go back to just by running a restore command

```
create restore point my_save_point guarantee flashback database;
```

Then you do your changes, you verify whatever you want to verify and if you need to rollback you just run

```
flashback database to restore point my_save_point ;
```

Comment: Appreciate your input, so if we re-store back to restore point, will it still have changes from Sunday till Tuesday or those need to be some how restored. I mean if we created restore point on Sunday if we restore to it do we lose database changes from Sunday till Tuesday? How often should we create restore point?

Comment: @user2101374 - Yes, you'd lose all the changes between the creation of the restore point and the current point in time.  All the changes between Sunday and Tuesday would be lost.  A restore point is conceptually a faster way to restore the database to a known point in time.